# Base64 image doesn't load in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, base64

I have base64 converted image and put on container background like this:

```
background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
```

Chrome and other browsers open it without any problem, except Mozilla Firefox. It show me blank image and when I try to open image manually, it gives me error:

> The image: "*data:image/png;base64,iV...5CIIA=*" cannot be displayed
>   because it contains errors

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix?

Here is the fiddle to try: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/QUXV5/

Comment: Reproduced here - not sure what the problem is though.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Did you tried to open this fiddle in Firefox? Does it work?

Comment: How did you get the base64 at the first place? A `base64 -> img -> canvas -> base64` routine produced different result: http://jsfiddle.net/QUXV5/4/ (although the result of Chrome and Opera Presto are different too).

Comment: do you have a link to the image somewhere on the web?  i got it to work in firefox using a jpg. http://jsfiddle.net/QUXV5/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QUXV5/8/ here is one working for png... funny though when i look at your fiddle the url('') code in between displays red on my screen. the fiddles that i have done displays in black

Comment: I used [Enigma64](http://getenigma64.com/) tool for Photoshop to generate Base64 sources. Looks like this extension produces wrong code.

Comment: this is the one i used... http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/

Comment: Enigma64 has also caused similar issues for me in Firefox.

Comment: @jessegavin which version do you have? This bug as fixed for me after update

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there's something wrong with the actual base64 data. See similar [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/QUXV5/6/) based on a `image/png;base64` file.

Try using these tools to [encode](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker) and [decode](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) your files.