# Base64 image does not appear in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, base64

The website www.duosear.ch uses the following CSS to display a Base64 image (in the top-right corner). It works in all browsers except Firefox.

```
.ob-button .ob-logo {
    height: 26px;
    padding: 3px;
    float: left;
    content:url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: You need to use background for this purposes, it's the right way to make it. See my answer ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 image doesn't load in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369370/base64-image-doesnt-load-in-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not problem of base64 but problem in the [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property: It is supported only for `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements in Firefox (and in specs).

Comment: Yes, and it's a bug of the other browsers to render `content` CSS property outside of pseudo `::after` and `::before`.

Answer (score 3):

As @myf said in his answer, `content` it's limited to `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements. In your case, you **must** use `background`:

```
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
```

That's the correct way to make this.

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Answer (score -2):

I think there is a solution already for your question on stackoverflow: [Base64 image doesn't load in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369370/base64-image-doesnt-load-in-firefox)